# How to restrict access to Pipelines in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I need to restrict access so that a user can NOT:

1. See or access Pipelines, or any of its sub-features, including Builds, Releases, Library, Task groups, Deployment groups
2. Create or edit build pipelines

I followed this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/set-permissions?view=vsts

I set all permissions to Deny. However, the user can still do both (1) and (2) above.

Question: Can I do either (1) or (2)?

Comment: i dont know if those are additive, but you need to make sure user isn't part of some security group that gives him access to do whatever you are trying to prevent him from doing

Comment: @4c74356b41 What is the exact Security setting I need to set to restrict access? The Security settings I set following the linked article seem like they are applicable only to Builds. Releases, etc, may very well have their own security settings. I want it so that all Pipeline features are disabled/in-accessible.

Comment: The user is part of Valid Users/Contributors. I've created a group under this called Developers, and if anything, I've Denied several permissions within these groups. I've not explicitly set anything to 'Allow'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **Organization Settings** under **Security** you can set:

- Manage build resources
- Use build resources
- View build resources

I'd say those should be **Deny**.

I have personally encountered some permission caching issue when testing these things.
Logging out and back in often doesn't change permissions right away.

**Update:**
Under Pipelines->Release you can click the 3 dots and there is a security subsite there containing these:
[image: Release Permissions]

Adding the user or group and setting Deny on those settings fixed it for me.
This unfortunatly seems to be on a Release-Pipeline basis.

**Update2:**
You can go into folder view when looking at releases, you can then create a folder to put all your release-pipelines into, then on a folder basis you can set the security settings to deny for you user or group, that way it will be inherited to every folder.

Developers need to remember to create release pipelines in that folder though.

[image: Folder based permission]

You need to have pipelines in the root or you wont be able to see the security button. (tested in new and old navigation design)

Comment: After a quick test on our system my test user can still see **Releases** and **Deployment groups** but not anything build related, i'll check back later to see if thats still the case after possible caches clear.

Comment: @Ash I noticed that i could remove the content of Deployment groups by clicking security under the deployment group itself and removing contributors (which i had my test user inside) there isn't a Deny permission anywhere else i can find, and you can still see the menu but not the content.

Comment: @Ash see my updated answer, it restricts access also viewing, but you can still see the menu items, which means it looks like you can create release pipelines and deployment groups, they have no create button though, so it's actually not possible.

Comment: Thanks Jim. Update2 worked for me. I've tried it for Builds and my test user indeed cannot view or create any pipelines. I will test with Releases, Deployment Groups, etc, and let you know if the same technique works with those as well. On a side note, do you know if there's a way to kind of _import_ these settings for all your projects? 'Cause these particular security settings are per project, and I need these to be organisation wide.

Comment: @ash we've got a similar desire to limit standard ADO team members from being able to view release pipelines' release logs... ex. we've protected environment variables in Azure KeyVault, which ADO then protects in variable groups, but anyone with permissions to edit pipelines or YAML can simply dump variables to a log page in process. Do you know an effective way to limit the users that can read build/release logs?

Comment: @Ash I've also opened a specific question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68716833/how-can-azure-devops-pipeline-build-and-release-logs-be-locked-down-to-a-specifi