# Limited access user on Azure DevOps on-premise can add/delete folders

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

We have Azure DevOps on-premise server 2020.1 RTW, we wanted to add users/groups with limited access to Wiki pages only. We added the group to the project and added the user to the group and updated all the permissions from Project Security to: **Deny** except for: View project-level information permission (set to: Allow). Permissions have also been updated from Collection Security settings. The user currently can view Wiki pages but he can also add/delete Pipeline folders. Any idea on how can we revoke the folder deletion permission? Note: I followed the below articles but the issue still not resolved:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/set-permissions?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts

[How to restrict access to Pipelines in Azure DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53456787/how-to-restrict-access-to-pipelines-in-azure-devops)

Update: Included Image for access control summary for Pipeline level permissions:

[This is the access control summary for Pipeline security](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7dfv.png)

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge we may set different level of pipeline permissions for the users.
Pipeline permissions are the permissions associated with pipelines in an Azure DevOps project. Permissions in Azure DevOps are hierarchical and can be set at the organization, server (for on-premises), project, and object levels.

Object-level permissions are designed to be more granular than organization-level permissions. For example, a user could have access to your Azure repository thanks to their organization-level permissions. However, that same user could be prevented from running a pipeline manually because of that pipeline's permissions.
Here is the reference for pipeline permissions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops#pipeline-permissions-reference

This for access levels in azure devops
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have included a screenshot of the access control summary of the pipeline level permissions in the original post, and the user has all permissions denied in collection and project levels except for: View project-level information permission in Project security which should allow him to view Wiki pages as per our original request. As per my understanding the user should not be allowed to add/delete folders in the pipeline level if all access are denied, not sure why he still able to do so. Note: user is not able to see the contents of the folder but he can delete it.