# How can Azure DevOps pipeline build and release logs be locked down to a specific group?

Tags: security, logging, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

**Background:**

Our team has removed sensitive information from code and configuration files, instead placing values in Azure KeyVault with Azure DevOps variables collections associated. This effectively prevents users from seeing variables in code, and values in the variables collection, but it does not limit values being written to build/release logs.

**Question**:

What options are available for (1) excluding access to build/release logs and (2) restricting pipeline editing?

*Correction: Values are written to the logs, but values coming from Key Vault are masked as `***` values. This resolves our problem, but the overarching question remains.*

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that there is no such method could only exclude the access to build and release Logs.

Based on your requirements, you could try to restrict the following permission.

For Build Pipeline, you could limit the **View builds** and **Edit build pipeline**.

[image]

Then the user will have no access to see the Builds and Edit the Pipeline.

For Release Pipeline, you could limit the **View releases** and **Edit release pipeline**.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Kevin. Are your images available at a different URL? Our business firewall blocks that domain. Also, can you update the answer with URLs to the supporting Microsoft documentation. It would help other users find the documentation supporting your answer.

Comment: @one.beat.consumer Please refer to this doc about [Pipeline Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops) and [Release Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops#set-release-permissions)

Comment: Thank you Kevin. Are PRs available from local repos back to the ADO/GitHub repo it is already associated with? That I am not finding examples on using VS's new Git module. Only on the old feature with the PR icon.

Comment: @one.beat.consumer. Based on your description, it seems that this is a new issue? I suggest taht you could create a new ticket for this issue . Then we can better help you.

Comment: I think I may be misunderstanding git. I understand PR from the remote repo to another, and the feature works fine. But I am not sure if you can gate using PRs to a repo you have directly mapped. Ex. /obc to origin/obc via Push, then origin/obc to /master via PR makes sense... but if someone has a local /master can they submit a PR to the origin/master? Perhaps this is something git doesn't do?

Comment: @one.beat.consumer. It seems that the question is not related to the current ticket right? I suggest that you could create a new ticket to report the new issue

Comment: You are right. Another ticket will be created. Thanks Kevin.